# React button does not show up

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm beginner on React, and trying to learn and improve, here i have a button which is needed to be clicked and after that should appear bunch of numbers like this 1:1 1:2 1:3, but here i seem to have a problem, my button does not appear, just numbers from URL appears, and i also have css to my button which is not working either when refreshing the page css works just for 1 second then disappear and im not getting any error message...

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Button extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        var proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        var url = "http://*****.******.com/numbers.txt";
        fetch(proxyurl + url) // https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://example.com
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(contents => document.write(contents))
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div className="whole">
            <button onClick={this.componentWillMount} >Increment</button>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Button;
```

```css
.whole {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

english is not my mother language so sorry for mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentWillMount` is a lifecycle event of the component and shouldn't be used like this ([also it is recommended that `componentWillMount` is no longer used](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)).

If you want the button to retrieve data you need to create a new function and assign it to the `onClick` prop of the button. eg:

```
handleClick = () => {
    var proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    // more code
    .then(contents => this.setState({ responseText: contents }))
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="whole">
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Increment</button>
        </div>
        <div>{this.state.responseText}</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks you, you have few mistakes in the code here is improved from yours :  render() {
        return (
            <div className="whole" >
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Increment</ button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Comment: it is saying now that : Avoid using document.write(). what is good replace for document.write ?

Comment: Try `console.log` if you just want to to output the data to the console.

Comment: i want to show it to user, if i put it to console just i can see it.

Comment: In that case you'll need to assign the response contents to the state.

Comment: can you possibly help with that here in comments, just for learning

Comment: I've updated the code example, but I suggest reading the React getting started guide. It will answer this question and give you a solid grounding in other concepts - https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.

Comment: i did as you suggested and got this message : Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? then i put it inside one div and got this error : 'contents' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: My example was just an example, you have to place setState within your `then` call. Code modified.